# Javascript - setInterval to change element's position

Tags: javascript, position, setinterval

I'm trying to work out how to move an element across the screen. I don't want to use JQuery's animate() method because I need more precise control. Here is the basic idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/9RLkJ/

```
setInterval(function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
    // Increase the top position by 1 pixel
    e.style.top = '+1px';
    // If the top position is greater than 100px, set it to 100px
    if (parseInt(e.style.top) > 100) { e.style.top = '100px'; }
}, 1000);
```

Thank you.

Comment: yet another 'i tried something 5 minutes and failed, now could you do it for me?' question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
var s = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    var eLeftPos = e.offsetLeft;
    e.style.left = (eLeftPos + s) + 'px';

}, 1000);
```

The above code will move the box to right;

working demo [move the box to bottom](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/9RLkJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`var top= document.getElementById("aDiv").style.top;
     setInterval(function() {
        top += 1;
        var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
        // Increase the top position by 1 pixel
        e.style.top = top + 'px';
        // If the top position is greater than 100px, set it to 100px
        if (parseInt(e.style.top) > 100) { e.style.top = '100px'; }
    }, 1000);`